# Running java application on Amazon AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made an EC2 VPC RHEL instance and deployed a java application running embedded jetty web server. For a simple understanding, this web application is serving basic HTML request. For my initial test, I made a security group that allows all incoming and outgoing traffic (All  All 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0).

I was expecting to browse the web page from public IP address but somehow it's not working. I also verified that Jetty is listening on 0.0.0.0. So, jetty doesn't seem a problem. I spent half a day in figuring it out but it's not working and not able to figure out the cause.

I then made a very basic TCP server(https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) and deployed on same AWS ec2 instance and then I tried to send the request from the client as a TCP client from my system and it doesn't work.

However, I am transferring files from WinSCP and running the commands from putty with this public IP only. This means that public IP is not a problem.

I can see the only difference with putty, WinSCP and my java client is that with putty, I am also providing the private key as part of authorization process(in auth) but wherein java or for the browser, I am accessing it directly.

Not able to understand where the problem can be. Is there a problem in DNS translation from public IP calls(ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.xx-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com) to private IP calls or this a problem of authorization?

Below is the Netstat trace of AWS(Web server running on 8080, I run jvm on IP4 stack with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true)

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo netstat -plnt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9321/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1627/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1091/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1627/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1091/master

Any help?

Comment: Did you open port 8080 on the security group?

Comment: I already have mentioned that "I made a security group that allows all incoming and outgoing traffic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother readers. I did everything and still, the problem was occurring. Then I gave the client program to one of my colleague who is on his home network and there it works...

So, the problem was not in AWS but somehow in my corporate network security that is blocking the request.

Comment: It is quite common for companies to block ports other than DNS, HTTP, HTTPS (and maybe FTP, SSH, and SMTP/POP3/IMAP if needed). It makes it a challenge to test against webapps on port 8080. You can use SSH local port forwarding (ssh -i user.pem -L 9000:localhost:8080 ec2-user@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com) or iptables port redirection or even an ELB with port forwarding (80 to 8080) to allow you to connect out of your firewall on port 80 with subsequent redirection to port 8080.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod for the tip.